# Django run function periodically in background

Tags: django

I have a function that fetches data and needs to be run periodically.
All I care about is running it every 30 seconds.

I searched and found the following options -

1. celery
2. django-apscheduler
3. Apscheduler

I have tried Apscheduler using BackgroundScheduler and it has this problem that it'll run a new scheduler for each process.
I am completely new to scheduling functions and have no idea which one I should use or if there is a better way.

Comment: I use celery as background periodical task manager

Comment: you have to use `beat` to check and spawn tasks after 30 seconds and `worker` for actual work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue and solved it by creating a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and scheduling it on the web server.

Within the root of the app, create management/commands directory:

```
some_app/
__init__.py
models.py
management/
    commands/
        dosomething.py
tests.py
views.py
```

---

```
// dosomething.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Description of the action here'

   def handle(self):
        print('Doing something')
        return
```

To confirm if it's working, run `python manage.py dosomething`

The scheduling itself depends on which web server you are using. In my case it was Heroku and I used their [Scheduler add-on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduling-custom-django-management-commands).